# DataTable and List object comparison

Tags: visual-studio, list, datatable

i m a part of an ERP solution team and want to measure the performance in terms of development. By a simple process a DataTable is populated from database with 10000 odd records and on other hand a List object is filled with the same records.

my question is, which one is the lightweight and performance measurable object and why.

Comment: Why don't you measure it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question says that a `List<MyObject>` can be cheaper than a `DataTable` when primitive/value (unboxed) data types are used:

- [List using more memory than DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772077/listobject-using-more-memory-than-datatable)

The answer to this question says that creating a `List<MyObject>` is even cheaper if you know the count when you create the `List`.

i.e. `List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>(10);`

- [DataTable to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709035/datatable-to-listobject)